# How to hide my sensitive info such as username and password in my apex form in my visualforce page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Below is my code snippet where I am passing my nab username and password for payment integration. How can I hide those password and username? I am using post method.

```
<apex:form id="register" onsubmit="return showPaymentOptions();">
<input type="hidden"  id="courseIdT" name="courseIdT" value="testcourse" />
<input type="hidden"  id="nabnameT" name="nabnamet" value="test"/>
<input type="hidden"  id="nabpwdT" name="nabpwdT" value="testpwd" />
<input type="hidden"  id="amtT" name="amtT" value="testamt" />
<input type="hidden"  id="rdctUrlT" name="rdctUrlT" value="testurl" />
```

I want to hide the parameters nabnameT and nabpwdT.

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Can you add some more context to this? Competently constructed payment portals typically offer ways to do this safely.

Comment: If you mean hiding it from someone looking at the page (or the source), or with access to the POST data that you send, then you can't. If you mean hiding it in transmission, obviously you should use HTTPs to stop it being intercepted. But maybe there's another way to achieve your overall requirement? If you give more details, perhaps someone can suggest it

Comment: I want to hide it from viewing those parameters in console log ie devtools in browsers

Comment: you can't. Everyone has access to the dev tools, if they know about it. Your only solution is to find a way to avoid doing this in a browser. Of course, if the user is passing _their own_ payment details, then it's of less concern, although a malicious plugin/extension could attempt to steal it, but that's the same for every website. Perhaps you can be clearer about why you think this is necessary?